# Toxic painted on gardens bed

Tags: watering, lawn-repair, sunlight, toxicity, alocasia

I am new to gardening. I painted my gardens bed with toxic paint . Please what can I do to fix this. I do not know what to do . I am new.

Comment: What type of paint did you use on your raised (I assume) beds, and how do you know it's toxic?

Comment: more details please!

Comment: There's a broad range of paints you shouldn't eat or drink that are not an issue when cured (still don't eat them, please.) Likewise, if you did not paint the INSIDE of your beds the paint won't be in contact with the soils anyway.